# Get the particular rows in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I have two csv files.

One is as follows:

```
"CONS_NO","DATA_DATE","KWH_READING","KWH_READING1","KWH"
"1652714033","2015/1/12","4747.3800","4736.8000","10.5800"
"3332440062","2015/1/12","408.6800","407.8200","0.8600"
"7804314033","2015/1/12","1794.3500","1792.5000","1.8500"
"0114314033","2015/1/12","3525.2000","3519.4400","5.7600"
"1742440062","2015/1/12","3097.1900","3091.4100","5.7800"
"8230100023","2015/1/12","1035.0500","1026.8400","8.2100"
```

About six million rows in all.

The other is as follows:

```
6360609057
8771218657
1338004100
2500009393
9184968250
9710581700
8833903141
```

About 10 thousand rows in all.

The second csv file has the CONS_NO only. I want to find the rows in the first csv file corresponding to the number in the second csv file; and delete the other rows in the first csv file in Python.

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: Pandas supports [joining two DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging). Try solving it on your own and edit the question  with some code if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the two `DataFrame` using the merge method in `pandas`.

I change your example data to the following:

`test1.csv` is:

```
"CONS_NO","DATA_DATE","KWH_READING","KWH_READING1","KWH"
"1652714033","2015/1/12","4747.3800","4736.8000","10.5800"
"3332440062","2015/1/12","408.6800","407.8200","0.8600"
"7804314033","2015/1/12","1794.3500","1792.5000","1.8500"
"8833903141","2015/1/12","3525.2000","3519.4400","5.7600"
"1742440062","2015/1/12","3097.1900","3091.4100","5.7800"
"8833903141","2015/1/12","1035.0500","1026.8400","8.2100"
```

`test2.csv' is:

```
6360609057
8771218657
1338004100
2500009393
9184968250
9710581700
8833903141
```

you can now merge them using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', names=['CONS_NO'])

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='CONS_NO')
```

it gives the following output:

```
    CONS_NO     DATA_DATE   KWH_READING KWH_READING1    KWH
0   8833903141  2015/1/12   3525.20     3519.44         5.76
1   8833903141  2015/1/12   1035.05     1026.84         8.21
```